# why is my python code returning text:'my string' instead of just my string?

Tags: python, xlrd

my code snippet looks like this:

```
for current_row in range(worksheet.nrows):
    fname_text = worksheet.row(current_row)[0]
    lname_text = worksheet.row(current_row)[1]
    cmt = worksheet.row(current_row)[2]
    print (fname_text, lname_text, cmt)
```

this prints:

```
text:'firstname' text:'lastname' text'the cmt line'
```

i want it just to return:

```
firstname lastname the cmt line
```

what do i need to change to make this happen?

Comment: Is "text:" located within worksheet.row(current_row)? Because from the question it seems like that it being printed with your actual strings...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what `Cell` objects look like:

```
>>> sheet.row(0)
[text:u'RED', text:u'RED', empty:'']
>>> sheet.row(0)[0]
text:u'RED'
>>> type(sheet.row(0)[0])
<class 'xlrd.sheet.Cell'>
```

You can get at the wrapped values in a few ways:

```
>>> sheet.row(0)[0].value
u'RED'
>>> sheet.row_values(0)
[u'RED', u'RED', '']
```

and remember you can access cells without going via `row`:

```
>>> sheet.cell(0,0).value
u'RED'
```