# Extract values from Excel spreadsheet

Tags: python, python-3.x, xlrd

I want to remove some words from a list of words. I have a list with a recurring word and I want to get rid of it and I have no idea. I don't know whether I need to use a whole loop or regex.

```
from xlrd import open_workbook,error_text_from_code

book = open_workbook(inp)

sheet0 = book.sheet_by_index(0)

x = 0
y = 0
countr = sheet0.nrows
countc = sheet0.ncols
names = ''
variables = []
"different variables-----------------"
while x < countr -1:
     x = x+1
     y = y+1
     cell = sheet0.cell(y,0)

names = names+ str(cell)
cell = sheet0.cell(y,1)

variables.append(cell)

country_text = names
countries = ', '.join(re.findall("('.*?')", country_text))
countries = countries.split()

print (variables)
print (countries)
```

What I get :

```
[number:150000.0, number:140000.0, number:300000.0]
```

and I need

```
[150000, 140000, 300000]
```

Comment: How did you get `'Frogs', 'Hogs', 'Dogs', 'Logs' ` from the first string? They don't appear to have anything to do with each other.

Comment: This seems very non-sequitur

Comment: i didnt get the frogs string. i need the same layout of the frogs string from my first string.

Comment: So you want `'usa', 'uk', 'netherlands'`? Why didn't you say so in the first place?

Comment: this is the question of the week for me

Comment: ill edit it to make it clear

Comment: iv edited it to make it clear

Comment: Is the output supposed to be a string or a list? Do you want `"'usa', 'uk', 'netherlands'"` or `['usa', 'uk', 'netherlands']`?

Comment: in a string. so "'usa', 'uk', 'netherlands'". and the numbers in a list

Comment: The [`json`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html?highlight=json#json) module might be helpful here.

Comment: If I ask myself "what's the real problem he's facing?", I think it's that you're working with `xlrd` and have `Cell` objects instead of strings and numbers.  If so, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21948935/why-is-my-python-code-returning-textmy-string-instead-of-just-my-string) may be useful.

Comment: @DSM good spot... So access a `.value` attribute might be worth while, or if `Cell` objects aren't required then use `cell_value` instead...

Comment: i have a while loop that extracts all the information in an exel spread sheet that has values. thanks for putting up a solution the first one works flawlessly. the second throws up error. i think it is what DSM spotted and is the xlrd

Comment: @user3379346 include the code you're using to do the looping and someone will be able to show you how to fix it :)

Comment: i have updated it again :) sorry im new at this

Comment: @user3379346 no worries - now it's a good question - I've voted to re-open it...

Comment: Use `cell_value` instead of `cell`...

Answer (score 0):

If you use a loop you can access to the value of a cell using this function:

```
sheet0.cell_value(curr_row, curr_cell)
```