# Changing values in an list?

Tags: list, python-3.x

I want to remove some words from a list of words. I have a list with a recurring word and I want to get rid of it and I have no idea. I don't know whether I need to use a whole loop or regex.

```
from xlrd import open_workbook,error_text_from_code

book = open_workbook(inp)

sheet0 = book.sheet_by_index(0)

x = 0
y = 0
countr = sheet0.nrows
countc = sheet0.ncols
names = ''
variables = []
"different variables-----------------"
while x < countr -1:
     x = x+1
     y = y+1
     cell = sheet0.cell(y,0)

names = names+ str(cell)
cell = sheet0.cell(y,1)

variables.append(cell)

country_text = names
countries = ', '.join(re.findall("('.*?')", country_text))
countries = countries.split()

print (variables)
print (countries)
```

What I get :

```
[number:150000.0, number:140000.0, number:300000.0]
```

and I need

```
[150000, 140000, 300000]
```

Comment: It doesn't really help to repost your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22177313/extract-values-from-excel-spreadsheet)

Comment: SO doesnt like duplicates. Just edit your answer if you have anything to add next time.